# Автообновление элемента страницы на js.

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем, имеется кусочек кода на html. Точнее строчка, обозначающая как-бы колличество личных сообщений. Нужно собрать код на js, который будет автоматически обновлять эту строчку в n - ое колличество секунд. Желательно, если бы это был обновляющийся `<div>`.

Сама строчка выглядит так:

```
<a href="{U_PRIVATEMSGS}">{PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO}</a>
```

Comment: > Нужно собрать код на js...

Ну, раз нужно, то дело святое - нужно собирать. А вопросик ваш в чем состоит?

Comment: Собственно, как это сделать.

Comment: Алгоритм прост: 

1. Используем **setInterval()** или **setTimeout()** (*в зависимости от поставленной задачи*). 
2. Внутри функции, указанной выше, отправляем ajax-запрос, ответом на который, будут данные для обновления вашей строки/элемента.
3. И наконец, используем нужный метод jQuery для вставки данных: **text()**, **html()** etc/

Comment: Эээ.. Не совсем понял. Ну, попробовал так:

setInterval(function() {
$("#update_ls").load("ls.php");
}, 1000);


Собственно, в ls.php просто продублировал мой див. Но как именно вывести, так и не понял. И вообще, правильно- ли сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Частично правильно, но я бы не стал использовать метод **load()** в данном случае (*ИМХО*). Я только понятия не имею, что у вас происходит на странице **ls.php**. По идее, вы должны вытаскивать данные по кол-ву личных сообщений из БД и именно эти данные отправлять в ответе. В общем, схема должна быть примерно следующей:

**JS**

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path_to/ls.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {userPrivMess: uid}, // Если личные данные вытаскиваются для определенного юзверя
        success: function(data){
            // data - сформированный ответ на стороне сервера
            $("#update_ls").text('Обновление: ' + data);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST['userPrivMess'])) $upm = $_POST['userPrivMess'];
if(isset($upm)){
    // вытаскиваем данные из БД, получаем кол-во сообщений
    // и формируем ответ:
    echo json_encode($count_priv_mess);
    exit;
}
```

Схематическую работу, можно [глянуть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QeZqJ/)